# python how to create json file in runtime?

Tags: python, json, multithreading, runtime

i'm trying to code in multithreading,one of my thread supposed to create a file ,and other thread should use the file. the thread sync well.
the problem is that the file object writing into the disk when the code finish or when i'm press the terminate button (i'm using PyCharm pro).

little example:
1. i tried to use **service** that call other script **test1** , but it doesn't work well.
i supposed that if **test1** will create the file , he can do that many times as long as **service** didn't finish the running .

2. i tried to create a file and then to use while true- to imagine that the code is keep running
   **my question is how can i force my code to create the file before my main code finish?**

**service.py**

```
import time
import runpy
import test1

def anotherChance(global_vars=None, local_vars=None):
    with open("test1.py") as f:
        code = compile(f.read(), "test1.py", 'exec')
        exec(code, global_vars, local_vars)

def service_func():
    print('service func')
    print('while loop')
    while True:
        print(1234)
        time.sleep(5)
        test1.some_func()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #exec(open("test1.py").read()) ##1 another wrong sol

    #anotherChance() ##2 another wrong sol
    #service_func()

    test1.some_func()
    service_func()
```

**test1.py**

```
import os

def tempreding ():
    with open('betext_file.json', 'w') as file:
        file.write('helloo')
        print(file.fileno())



def some_func():
    print('in test 1, unproductive')
    #infile=open('abcs.json','w')
    #infile.write('aabbcc')
    tempreding()

if __name__ == '__main__':

   #print("I am a test")
   #print(" I do nothing .")
   some_func()
```

Comment: This isn't multithreading at all though, it's running sequentially.

Comment: You are not running the second file in a new thread, but in your main thread. If you want to use it in a second thread you should start it in a second thread, e.g.  with the `threading` library.

Comment: i know its not a multi ,i tried to make it simple . instead to use the original code. so i gave an example.  if i will get an answer for that situation i could know what to do in the original code